# 20.04 graphical glitch--top few rows of pixels "overflow" to bottom of screen

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have an odd glitch on my Ubuntu installation and can't seem to find any solutions online. Doesn't help that it's quite tricky to put into words.

The top row of pixels on my screen seem to be "overflowing" to the bottom, and there is a lot of glitchiness on that bottom row. Probably easier to see in a video: https://streamable.com/dhzx0h

My laptop has an Nvidia card which is using the 460 drivers. I use Nvidia prime to manage the graphics card, and have it permanently set to use the internal graphics which I can confirm it is doing.

I have been running the same config for well over a year with no issues. This glitchiness started out of the blue a few weeks ago.

What I have tried:

1. Rolling back and updating Nvidia drivers.
2. Booting into my windows installation where no such glitch is present, seemingly confirming that there is no hardware fault.
3. Connecting external monitors--no glitch. It seems to be only when using the laptop screen
4. Disabling all Gnome extensions

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me slightly crazy.

Comment: Either you haven't set your screen resolution correctly, as there's black at the bottom of the screen, or you're showing a Gnome extension that could cause the problem, as there's a bottom bar that shouldn't show with extensions disabled.

Comment: @heynnema Nope, the screen resolution is correct, that is the bezel of the laptop. As I said, I have tried disabling gnome extensions with the same results. You are correct that the bottom bar is an extension.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? I have the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE installed. I also have NVIDIA drivers, I've updated them but glitch still preserves. I tried to decrease rzte from 300Hz to 60Hz, or change resolution, but it doesn't affect the glitch.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this, the problem was with the display setting. It had somehow reverted to ~40 hz instead of 60. Once I fixed this the issue was gone.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, but it is already on ~60Hz. What I've been doing to mask this issue is to change resolution and revert changes. When it reverts, the glitch goes away, but every time I turn the PC on, it comes back. Did your change fix it long term for you?